# convergence of a “nice ” subseries of a divergent series 2

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$S_0 := a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$$ is a divergent series of positive terms whose limit approaches 0. Obtain a subseries,called a first-stage nice subseries, $$S_1 := b_1+b_2+b_3+\cdots$$ from $S_0$ by deleting all terms with **even** subscripts. If it is not convergent obtain a second-stage nice subseries $S_2$ from $S_1$ by deleting all terms with **even** subscripts.If not convergent continue this process.
What is the necessary or sufficient condition for $S_0$ to adopt a convergent nice subseries?

Comment: By "nice" do you mean convergent, or what? That needs to be defined.

Comment: Although edited now, it still leaves open what extra property is meant by "nice".

Comment: Well if "nice" just means convergent, I suggest leaving that term out of the question and just using "convergent".

Comment: I think this edit has made clear the notion of nice subseries @coffeemath

Answer (score 0):

If the series is monotone, then all of the given subsequences will diverge.  So, a necessary condition is that the series not be monotone.

Clearly, this is not a sufficient condition.

However the point that it raises is that there probably isn't going to be much more to say about this question.  In particular you aren't going to get any kind of a sufficient condition based on the series decreasing "fast enough" - if the series is divergent, then it can't decrease fast enough for subsequences to be convergent.